# Simplify $3(3^{2k+1}) - 3(3^k) + 2(3^{2k+2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I am trying to simplify this $3(3^{2k+1}) - 3(3^k) + 2(3^{2k+2})$ to get to $3^{k+1}(3^{k+2}-1)$. I have tried doing this:

> $3(3^{2k+1}) - 3(3^k) + 2(3^{2k+2})$
>
> = $3^{k+1}\space[3(3^k)\space - \space3(3^{-1})\space + \space2(3^{k+1})]$

But according to WolframAlpha, the two equations above are not equivalent. Where am I going wrong?

Sidenote: I am 100% sure that $3(3^{2k+1}) - 3(3^k) + 2(3^{2k+2})$ simplifies to $3^{k+1}(3^{k+2}-1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $$3^{k+1}[3(3^k)-3(3^{-1})+2(3^{k+1})]$$
This can be reduced as follows 
$$\begin{align}&3^{k+1}[3^{k+1}-1+2\cdot3^{k+1}]\\=&3^{k+1}[3^{k+1}(1+2)-1]\\=&3^{k+1}[3\cdot3^{k+1}-1]\\=&3^{k+1}[3^{k+2}-1]\end{align}$$
I don't understand why Wolfram would disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You make things more complicated than they really are:
\begin{align}3(3^{2k+1}) - 3(3^k) + 2(3^{2k+2})&=3^{2k+2}-3^{k+1}+2\cdot3^{2k+2}=3\cdot3^{2k+2}-3^{k+1}\\&=3^{2k+3}-3^{k+1}=3^{k+1}(3^{k+2}-1)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I guess setting $t=3^{k+1}$ cannot hurt in this context.

$3(3^{2k+1})-3(3^k)+2(3^{2k+2})=t^2-t+2t^2=3t^2-t=t(3t-1)$